# Pygame rect.move_ip does not work

Tags: python, pygame, rect

So I tried to program my first real game in Pygame (without using sprites) but the collision detection, made with pygame.rect, did not work, so I tried to find the problem and it tourned out that rect.mouve ip did not worked.
Heres the sourcecode:

```
import pygame
from splayer import *
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption('Mein erstes Spiel')
white = (255,255,255)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
gravity = 1
player = Spieler(10,100)
g1 = pygame.image.load('gunter1.png')
g2 = pygame.image.load('gunter.png')
b1 = pygame.image.load('block.png')
gameLoop=True
y2 = 400
while gameLoop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type == pygame.QUIT):
            gameLoop=False
    window.fill(white)
    window.blit(b1, (10,y2))
    block1 = pygame.Rect(10, y2, 100, 100)
    window.blit(b1, (100,y2))
    block2 = pygame.Rect(100, y2, 100, 100)
    window.blit(b1, (200,y2))
    block3 = pygame.Rect(200, y2, 100, 100)
    window.blit(b1, (300,y2))
    block4 = pygame.Rect(300, y2, 100, 100)
    window.blit(b1, (400,y2))
    block5 = pygame.Rect(400, y2, 100, 100)
    rplayer = pygame.Rect(player.x, player.y, 100, 100)
    rplayer.move_ip(player.x, player.y)
    if rplayer.colliderect(block1) == True:
        gravity = 0
    player.update(gravit)
    player.render(window, g1)
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        window.blit(g2, (player.x,player.y))
    if key[pygame.K_d]:
        player.x += 20
    if key[pygame.K_a]:
        player.x -= 20
    if key[pygame.K_w]:
        player.y -= 20
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(10)
pygame.quit()
```

And here is the player class "splayer.py" which I also wrote myself

```
class Spieler:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.v = 0
        self.rplayer = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 100, 100)
    def update(self, gravity):
        self.v+=gravity
        self.y+=self.v
    def render(self, window, g1):
        window.blit(g1, (self.x,self.y))
```

But the Part which makes problems is obviously this part:

```
rplayer = pygame.Rect(player.x, player.y, 100, 100)
rplayer.move_ip(player.x, player.y)
if rplayer.colliderect(block1) == True:
    gravity = 0
```

I hope you can find the problem

---

I still have some problems with implementing the code:

```
import pygame
from splayer3 import *
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption('Mein erstes Spiel')
white = (255,255,255)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
gravity = 1
player = Spieler
g1 = pygame.image.load('gunter1.png')
g2 = pygame.image.load('gunter.png')
b1 = pygame.image.load('block.png')
gameLoop=True
y2 = 400
while gameLoop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type == pygame.QUIT):
            gameLoop=False
    window.fill(white)

    window.blit(b1, (10,y2))
    block1 = pygame.Rect(10, y2, 100, 100)
    window.blit(b1, (100,y2))
    block2 = pygame.Rect(100, y2, 100, 100)
    window.blit(b1, (200,y2))
    block3 = pygame.Rect(200, y2, 100, 100)
    window.blit(b1, (300,y2))
    block4 = pygame.Rect(300, y2, 100, 100)
    window.blit(b1, (400,y2))
    block5 = pygame.Rect(400, y2, 100, 100)

    x, y = player.getPosition()
    player.move(x, y)
    #player.rplayer.move_ip(player.x, player.y)
    if player.rplayer.colliderect(block1) == True:
        gravity = 0
    player.update(gravity,)
    player.render(window, g1)
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        window.blit(g2, (player.x,player.y))
    if key[pygame.K_d]:
        player.x += 20
    if key[pygame.K_a]:
        player.x -= 20
    if key[pygame.K_w]:
        player.y -= 20
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(10)
pygame.quit()
```

And the Spieler class again:

```
import pygame
class Spieler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.v = 0
        self.rplayer = pygame.Rect(10, 100, 100, 100)

    def getPosition(self):
        return self.rplayer.x, self.rplayer.y

    def update(self, gravity):
        self.v+=gravity
        self.y+=self.v

    def render(self, window, g1):
        window.blit(g1, (self.x,self.y))

    def move(self, x, y):
        self.rplayer.move_ip(x, y)
```

I get the error:

File "spiel3.py", line 32, in 
    x, y = player.getPosition()
TypeError: unbound method getPosition() must be called with Spieler instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a rPlayer rectangle every time you start the loop. Later you move it, but the rectangle is never saved - you create a new one with the old values on the next iteration.

Instead of having x,y and rect values in the Spiele class, you should decide on one and stick to it. I think it is better to have a rect, and make a function that will return the coordinates if we ever need them.

```
def getPosition(self):
    return self.rplayer.x, self.rplayer.y
```

Remove `self.x` and `self.y` from the `Spiele` class.

To make it more clear we can create a move function for `Spieler` which will look like this:

```
def move(x,y):
    self.rplayer.move_ip(x,y)
```

Lastly, you want to change the movement code below to call move() instead of modifying `player.x` and `player.y`